# Schedule refresh PowerPivot excel on Sharepoint Online

Tags: excel, sharepoint, business-intelligence, powerpivot, sharepoint-online

I would like to know if is possible schedule a refresh workbook with power pivot data on Sharepoint Online.

I already searched in other posts but just found informations about only schedule this on Sharepoint Server

https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee637271(SQL.105).aspx

Thank you.

Comment: What type of data source populates your Power Pivot model? Is that source in the cloud or on prem?

Comment: It is an Analysis Services data source from a local instance that I will provide an external conexion

Answer (score 0):

To schedule refresh of Analysis Services look at Power BI and the Personal Gateway:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/09/03/new-version-of-personal-gateway-now-available.aspx